# Copy file to s3 from a url and make it public

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3

```
aws_session = Session(
aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
region_name=settings.AWS_DEFAULT_LAMBDA_REGION
)

s3_resource = aws_session.resource('s3')

def copy_audio_file(source_audio_url):
    url_validator = URLValidator()
    try:
        url_validator(source_audio_url)
    except ValidationError as e:
        raise CopyAudioFileException("Got error while trying to copy audio file. URL: {0}, Error: {1}".
                                 format(source_audio_url, e.message))

    filename = get_random_string(32) + ".mp3"
    destination_audio_url = settings.AWS_BASE_URL_S3 + settings.AWS_BUCKET_CALL_RECORDINGS + '/' + filename

    try:
        s3_resource.Object(settings.AWS_BUCKET_CALL_RECORDINGS, filename).copy_from(
        CopySource=source_audio_url)
    except ClientError as e:
        logger.exception(e)
        raise CopyAudioFileException("Got error while trying to copy audio file. URL: {0}, Error: {1}".
                                 format(source_audio_url, e.message))
return destination_audio_url
```

I am using the above function to copy file from a url to s3. I want to make this file public. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not clear what is the question. For a code review you can try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have successfully copied the file. Now i want tom change the permissions of the file to public.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `ACL='public-read'` in `copy_from` method.

```
s3_resource.Object(settings.AWS_BUCKET_CALL_RECORDINGS,filename) \
    .copy_from(CopySource=source_audio_url, ACL='public-read')
```